# Laravel Join Not Returning Specified Column

Tags: php, laravel, join

I have a table `jobs`. A job may have 1 or more rows in `jobs_days`

I want to return a list of `jobs` that have at least 1 'job day'. So I have this is my Jobs Model:

```
public function days(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\JobsDays', 'job_id', 'id');
}
```

Which works fine. However I need to have a list of jobs that have at least 1 job day, but sort this list by this job start date: `start2`(timestamp) column.
I have tried using:

```
$jobs = Jobs::has('days')
            ->leftJoin('jobs_days', function ($join) {
                $join->where('jobs_days.job_id', '=', 'jobs.id');
            })
            ->select('jobs.id','jobs_days.start2')
            ->orderBy('jobs_days.start2', 'asc')->paginate(15);
```

This won't return my `start2` date. If I use `on` in place of `where`, I get my `start2` column, but it now returns duplicate jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours, I found the solution. Using on in the join, I added a simple:

```
->groupBy('jobs.id')
```

Gives me distinct job.ids. Not sure why distinct doesn't work but this seems to do the job